# What's an appropriate design pattern for this hierarchical class structure?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I have a class that instantiates a hierarchy of classes. The interface should hide all of the internal hierarchy by presenting a single class reference. (An the interface to the classes at intermediate levels should hide internal implementation details the same way.) I am having a little difficulty deciding how to flow the interface parameters down to the lowest levels and to flow state changes up to the top level. What I have come up with gets messy.

I have seen some discussions of the **blackboard pattern** but, from what I have seen, it looks ad hoc and flat rather than hierarchical. (Although flat vs hierarchical may not be important.)

The class I have is a calendar view, subclasing UIView. The hierarchy includes a header class, a grid class (instantiated more than once), a tile class (instantiated many times), plus some helper classes. It's based on Keith Lazuka's kal calendar in Objective C. I've decided to reorganize it for my needs, and wanted to rethink this part of it before I introduce problems with flexibility.

My question is in the title.

Comment: Take a look at the class cluster pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the class cluster pattern in Cocoa Design Patterns. If I understand it right, it looks like subtype polymorphism, to me, where all of the objects at the lower levels of the hierarchy have a behavior that depends on the data type. I don't see how this helps with a hierarchy of objects that all have different behavior and rolls, but still have functional and parametric dependence in their behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that the KVO (Key Value Observer) design pattern makes sense for bubbling state information from the lower levels to the top. Only that state information that needs to flow up is observed at each of the corresponding layers.

In this application, a tapped tile event is sent to the observer at the next level up (the grid level), telling it that the user has selected a date, which is a property of the tile class.

At the grid level, it changes its state based on its current state and the new information that it's observer receives from the tile. (In my calendar, the user can select a range of dates by choosing start date and end date, and can continue tapping tiles to change his date range selection.) This changes state at the grid level translates into a change in the start and/or the end date, so an NSDictionary property is updated.

At the calendar level, an observer sees the startDate/endDate dictionary change. Regardless of which grid this came from (there are two grids, and only one of them is active at a time. The tiles and the calendar do not need to be aware of this) the calendar's start and end dates are updated.

The calendar is a view that is planted into one of the other views of the application, initialized with a month to be shown, and with a selected date range (start and stop dates). Information is flowed down from the top though the pointers to each of the immediate subviews at any layer. Those subviews take care of keeping their subviews configured. I have eliminate the need to add explicitly add delegate methods or callbacks, and that has simplified the connections from top to bottom. Connections only go the the immediate level above or below in the hierarchy.

This may not seem like much after all, because it looks rather straightforward. But it wasn't clear until I spent awhile thinking about it. I hope it gives others some ideas for their own code. I would still like to know if there are other suggestions responding to my question.